# JTable isn't getting updated

Tags: java, swing, serialization, jtable

I've created a currency exchange calculator imports its date from the internet, stores it in a .dat file, and also displays all its data inside a JTable.

It should work the following way, if you update the JTable, the exchange rates the calculator uses, will also change, it used to work just fine, until I needed to import the data for the JTable from the database itself.
I also have a method that manually update all the data in the database, that works as a stack, and the table and the calculator should always take the data from the last imported currency rates.

Now the problem is that, when you edit the table manually by yourself for the first time, it works perfectly, but if I'll update the data using the method, it will update the data as it should, and the calculator will use the updated data, but the table won't be effective anymore. meaning, after the method has been used, it doesn't update the table anymore, and editing manually the  data in the table won't affect the data that the calculator uses.

Is there any way to update the entire table while I update the database?
Right now it works the following way:
The JTable constructor takes the 1st element in the database, and when I update the database, I believe the table just doesn't affect at all.

I've created a more simplify code to show the issue:

```
package calc.test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class main_calc {

    private JFrame main_frame, table_frame;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JScrollPane scrollpane;
    private JTable my_table;
    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter;
    private String[] columns = { "Name", "Unit", "Currency", "Country", "Rate", "Change" };
    private JMenuItem view_table, updates;
    private JMenu File_;
    private JButton Show_value;
    private static JTextField result_field;
    private JTextField jtFilter;
    private static Database my_data;
    private JPanel top_right_frame, bottom_left_frame, bottom_right_frame;
    private JPanel table_panel;
    private static JComboBox<String> from_ComBox;
    private JLabel search_label;
    final static private String[] Currencies = { "NIS", "USD", "GBP", "JPY", "EUR", "AUD", "CAD", "DKK", "NOK", "ZAR",
            "SEK", "CHF", "JOD", "LBP", "EGP" };
    private boolean was_created = false;

    public main_calc() {
        my_data = new Database();
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        main_frame = new JFrame("My Currency Exchange Calcualtor");
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        File_ = new JMenu("File");
        File_.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        updates = new JMenuItem("Update currrencies");
        updates.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        updates.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {

            try {
                Extraction_BOI(my_data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        view_table = new JMenuItem("Table");
        table_frame = new JFrame("Currencies' Table");
        table_panel = new JPanel();
        table_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        table_frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        table_frame.setSize(540, 277);
        table_frame.setResizable(false);
        view_table.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        view_table.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
            if (!(was_created)) {
                try {
                    Table_Creation();
                    search_label = new JLabel();
                    search_label.setText("Search:");
                    table_panel.add(search_label, BorderLayout.WEST);
                    table_panel.add(jtFilter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    table_frame.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    table_frame.add(table_panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    jtFilter.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                            String text = jtFilter.getText();

                            if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                                rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                            } else {
                                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                            String text = jtFilter.getText();

                            if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                                rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                            } else {
                                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

            table_frame.setVisible(true);

            was_created = true;

        });

        Show_value = new JButton("Show");
        result_field = new JTextField(10);
        top_right_frame = new JPanel();
        bottom_right_frame = new JPanel();
        bottom_left_frame = new JPanel();
        from_ComBox = new JComboBox<>(Currencies);
        try {
            Extraction_BOI(my_data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        main_frame.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - main_frame.getSize().width / 2,
                dim.height / 2 - main_frame.getSize().height / 2);

        table_frame.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - table_frame.getSize().width / 2,
                dim.height / 2 - table_frame.getSize().height / 2);
    }

    public void start() {

        main_frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        menuBar.add(File_);
        File_.add(view_table);
        File_.add(updates);
        main_frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        main_frame.add(top_right_frame);
        main_frame.setResizable(false);
        main_frame.setSize(400, 200);
        main_frame.setVisible(true);
        top_right_frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        top_right_frame.add(from_ComBox);
        main_frame.add(bottom_left_frame);
        main_frame.add(bottom_right_frame);
        bottom_left_frame.add(Show_value);
        bottom_right_frame.add(result_field);

        Show_value.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                main_calc.get_table_cell();
            }
        });

        main_frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        });
    }

    public String[][] Extraction_BOI(Database my_data) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.boi.gov.il/currency.xml");
        String[] str = { "NAME", "UNIT", "CURRENCYCODE", "COUNTRY", "RATE", "CHANGE", "LAST_UPDATE" };
        String listOfAll[][] = new String[15][7];
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.connect();
        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        int i = 0, j = 1, k = 0;
        listOfAll[0][0] = "Shekel";
        listOfAll[0][1] = "1";
        listOfAll[0][2] = "NIS";
        listOfAll[0][3] = "ISR";
        listOfAll[0][4] = "1";
        listOfAll[0][5] = "0";
        listOfAll[0][6] = "-";
        // Copy XML Elements into NodeLists//
        NodeList listName = doc.getElementsByTagName(str[0]);
        NodeList listUnit = doc.getElementsByTagName(str[1]);
        NodeList listCurrencyCode = doc.getElementsByTagName(str[2]);
        NodeList listCountry = doc.getElementsByTagName(str[3]);
        NodeList listRate = doc.getElementsByTagName(str[4]);
        NodeList listChange = doc.getElementsByTagName(str[5]);

        // Copy all the NodeLists into String array named listOfAll//
        for (i = 0; i < listName.getLength(); i++, j++, k = 0) {
            listOfAll[j][k] = listName.item(i).getTextContent();
            k += 1;
            listOfAll[j][k] = listUnit.item(i).getTextContent();
            k += 1;
            listOfAll[j][k] = listCurrencyCode.item(i).getTextContent();
            k += 1;
            listOfAll[j][k] = listCountry.item(i).getTextContent();
            k += 1;
            listOfAll[j][k] = listRate.item(i).getTextContent();
            k += 1;
            listOfAll[j][k] = listChange.item(i).getTextContent();
            k += 1;
        }

        in.close();
        con.disconnect();
        try {
            my_data.put(listOfAll);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        my_data.serialize();
        return listOfAll;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                main_calc gui = new main_calc();
                gui.start();

            }

        });

    }
    public static void get_table_cell() {

        String[][] datas;
        datas = my_data.peek();
        int from_Index = from_ComBox.getSelectedIndex();

        String result = datas[from_Index][4];
        result_field.setText(String.valueOf(result));

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public void Table_Creation() throws Exception {
        this.my_table = new JTable(my_data.peek(), columns) {
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                if (my_table.getValueAt(row, 0) == "Shekel" || column != 4)
                    return false;
                return true;
            }
        };
        this.scrollpane = new JScrollPane(my_table);
        my_table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        TableColumn column = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            column = my_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);

            column.setPreferredWidth(30);

        }

        rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(my_table.getModel());
        jtFilter = new JTextField();
        my_table.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

    }

}
```

Database class:

```
    package calc.test;

import java.util.Vector;
import java.io.*;

 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Database extends Vector<String[][]> {

  Database() {
  super();
  }

 void put(String[][] o) {
  addElement(o);
  }

 String[][] peek() {
  if (isEmpty()) return null;
    return (String[][]) lastElement();
    }

void serialize(){
try {
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("mydata.dat");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    oos.writeObject(this);
    oos.close();
    }
 catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}

}
```

In the code I created I removed the interfaces and removed most of the stuff.

If you will update the table manually, and click on show, it will show the updated value you entered, so it does update the database, since the `get_table_cell` method always takes the data from the database. If you click on update from the menu, everything that you will update from now on will be in vain for the table, but the "calculator" will still use the updated value from the database.

Comment: `"I don't believe the rest of the code is needed, but if it does let me know..."` -- Please look at the [mcve] and the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) links to see *exactly* what code is needed. It's not the rest of the code for sure, but more code, enough so that we can compile, run the code unchanged (no database allowed), and experience the problem, but small enough to post here in your question as code-formatted text.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels , I've added more parts of the code, if he whole code is needed, let me know, so it will be easier to compile

Comment: Please read or re-read the links I've posted above. They will explain (and as I've already stated) why we definitely don't want to see the entire program, and why snippets that you're posting are not as helpful as what we're trying to get you to post. Please read the links *before* replying.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I will create a new question, with a new code that will simplify the problem, thanks, how can I close this 1?

Comment: You can, but wouldn't it be better to edit your existing question, no?

Comment: Before we jump through many, many flaming hoops to help you, can you confidently say that you understand the Model-View-Controller pattern that JTable relies on and that you know that when data changes, it's not the JTable you update, but rather, the TableModel? After a cursory glance over your code, you seem to be updating a matrix of your own devise, rather than an instance of TableModel or a custom TableModel.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I can confidently say that I do understand how this works. I've tried before to create a TableModel and sent it to JTable constructor, but  when I tried that, changing the values of the table didn't change the values of the database, and when I'm using the calculator, I want to to use the data from the database, and not from the table.
Edit: I'm working on a code right now to simplify and show you the problem.

Comment: It seems you might have an abstract understanding of MVC, but you aren't applying that understanding to JTable. Implement TableModel in a class and override all abstract methods like setValueAt(). When you get data from the database, use myTableModel.setValueAt(updatedValue, row, col). Then fire a table change event and you'll see the changes in your view. If you know MVC, then you know that JTable is a view -- nothing more, and updating it does nothing. Read the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and make sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, I posted the new code I created, you can see that I edit the table manually, and take data from the database itself, it will take the updated data, so it's not 'just a view' as you said, it does change the database itself.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've edited as much as I could, couldn't place less code there, it's less than a half of the code, hope it is good right now, it shows the problem as it should, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I did manage to solve this with a little workaround.

I've changed that the JTable constructor will receive a tableModel, and not a String[][] and columns, and that way, whenever I'm updating the database, I'm just editing the tableModel.

As for the calculator convert method, in the code above listed as `get_table_cell`, I've made it obtain the data from the JTable, and since I'm always updating the table each time I click the udpate button, the calculator will use an updated data all the time, so now when I edit the table manually, even after the first update, I still can give the calculator manual data, and not only from the database.

I've made it something like that:

Some of the table creation method:

```
public void tableCreation() throws Exception {
    modelTable = new DefaultTableModel(myDatabase.peek(), columns);
    BOI_Calculator.myTable = new JTable(modelTable);
```

The calculator method, which obtain data from the table:

```
outcome = convertFromSum * ((Double.parseDouble((String) myTable.getValueAt(fromIndex, 4)))
                / (Double.parseDouble((String) myTable.getValueAt(toIndex, 4))));
        outcome = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.####").format(outcome));
        outputField.setText(String.valueOf(outcome));
```

And that's how I update the database and the table each time I click the update button:

```
        extractData(myDatabase);
    String[][] temp = myDatabase.peek();
    DefaultTableModel temp2 = new DefaultTableModel(temp, columns);
    myTable.setModel(temp2);
```